# SWIG wrapper adding new_ prefix to the class name and unable to get class method

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have written wrapper for simple C++ void function that takes 2 string parameters.
For some reasons when I try to create an object of my class, I'm getting the name error that "name 'my class name' is not defined".
When I tried create object and specify new_ prefix before class name the object was created, but I'm still can't call my function with similar name tricks.
Bellow the code of interface and classes:

```
 %module python_module

%{
#include "python_wrapper.h"
%}

%import std_string.i

%include "python_module.h"
```

**python_wrapper.h**

```
#ifndef PYTHON_WRAPPER_H
#define PYTHON_WRAPPER_H

#include <string>

class Separator
{
public:
  Separator();
  ~Separator();

public:
  void separate(const std::string& Path, const std::string& destFolder);
};

#endif
```

**strong text**

```
#include "python_wrapper.h"
#include <separator.h>

Separator::Separator()
{
}

Separator::~Separator()
{
}

void Separator::separate(const std::string& Path, const std::string& destFolder)
{
  ::SomeSeparate(assemblyPath, destFolder);
}
```

I build everything with cmake.
when I run in terminal:

```
    python3
>>> from _MyModule import *
>>> separator = Separator()
I'm getting name error : name 'Separator' is not defined.
```

Can somebody help with this ?

IN same time, when I text

```
>>> separator = new_Separator()
```

the object creating, but even after this I unable to call my function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used pybin11 instead of SWIG. For my task that was much easier solution than with swig.